# How to nest JSON dictionary using key in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I would like to transform my json dictionary which has this structure:

```
[{'show_id': 's64',
  'type': 'TV Show',
  'title': '13 Reasons Why',
  'director': nan,
  'cast': "Dylan Minnette, Katherine Langford, Kate Walsh, Derek Luke, Brian d'Arcy James, Alisha Boe, Christian Navarro, Miles Heizer, Ross Butler, Devin Druid, Michele Selene Ang, Steven Silver, Amy Hargreaves",
  'country': 'United States',
  'rating': 'TV-MA',
  'duration': '4 Seasons',
  'Certificate': '16+',
  'Runtime_of_Episodes': '60 min',
  'Genre': 'Drama, Mystery, Thriller',
  'IMDB_Rating': 7.6,
  'No_of_Votes': 256630,
  '_id': '60dae6af60d63d1fa2508e15',
  'text': '13 Reasons Why . HashtagTheBest! ',
  'hashtags': '[]',
  'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
  'score2': 0.0,
  'text_cleaned__punctuation': '13 Reasons Why  HashtagTheBest '},
 {'show_id': 's64',
  'type': 'TV Show',
  'title': '13 Reasons Why',
  'director': nan,
  'cast': "Dylan Minnette, Katherine Langford, Kate Walsh, Derek Luke, Brian d'Arcy James, Alisha Boe, Christian Navarro, Miles Heizer, Ross Butler, Devin Druid, Michele Selene Ang, Steven Silver, Amy Hargreaves",
  'country': 'United States',
  'rating': 'TV-MA',
  'duration': '4 Seasons',
  'Certificate': '16+',
  'Runtime_of_Episodes': '60 min',
  'Genre': 'Drama, Mystery, Thriller',
  'IMDB_Rating': 7.6,
  'No_of_Votes': 256630,
  '_id': '60dae6af60d63d1fa2509aca',
  'text': 'RT @haeriiisund: [ Haechan short Au ]\n\n—13 Reasons Why \n\n“Let me tell you 13 things about him that will make you fall for him.”\n\n©haeriisun…',
  'hashtags': '[]',
  'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
  'score2': 0.0,
  'text_cleaned__punctuation': 'RT   Haechan short u  —13 Reasons Why “Let me tell you 13 things about him that will make you fall for him” ©haeriisun…'}]
```

Into this final result:

```
[{'show_id': 's64',
  'type': 'TV Show',
  'title': '13 Reasons Why',
  'director': nan,
  'cast': "Dylan Minnette, Katherine Langford, Kate Walsh, Derek Luke, Brian d'Arcy James, Alisha Boe, Christian Navarro, Miles Heizer, Ross Butler, Devin Druid, Michele Selene Ang, Steven Silver,   Amy Hargreaves",
  'country': 'United States',
  'rating': 'TV-MA',
  'duration': '4 Seasons',
  'Certificate': '16+',
  'Runtime_of_Episodes': '60 min',
  'Genre': 'Drama, Mystery, Thriller',
  'IMDB_Rating': 7.6,
  'No_of_Votes': 256630,
  'tweet': {'_id': '60dae6af60d63d1fa2508e15',
            'text': '13 Reasons Why . HashtagTheBest! ',
            'hashtags': '[]',
            'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
            'score2': 0.0,
            'text_cleaned__punctuation': '13 Reasons Why  HashtagTheBest '},
           {'_id': '60dae6af60d63d1fa2509aca',
            'text': 'RT @haeriiisund: [ Haechan short Au ]\n\n—13 Reasons Why \n\n“Let me tell  you     13 things about him that will make you fall for him.”\n\n©haeriisun…',
            'hashtags': '[]',
            'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
            'score2': 0.0,
            'text_cleaned__punctuation': 'RT   Haechan short u  —13 Reasons Why “Let me tell you 13  things about him that will make you fall for him” ©haeriisun…'}]
```

i tried to use itertools of groupby but without the expected results.
My datasets have 160316 rows. For each title of series or film there are as many rows as there are tweets.
Thanks to all who reply and have a good evening.

Comment: Show your coding attempt and what is wrong with it.  The "json dictionary" is not valid JSON or Python.  What is `nan`?  Make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that transforms your sample data:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import json

nan = float('nan')

data = [{'show_id': 's64',
  'type': 'TV Show',
  'title': '13 Reasons Why',
  'director': nan,
  'cast': "Dylan Minnette, Katherine Langford, Kate Walsh, Derek Luke, Brian d'Arcy James, Alisha Boe, Christian Navarro, Miles Heizer, Ross Butler, Devin Druid, Michele Selene Ang, Steven Silver, Amy Hargreaves",
  'country': 'United States',
  'rating': 'TV-MA',
  'duration': '4 Seasons',
  'Certificate': '16+',
  'Runtime_of_Episodes': '60 min',
  'Genre': 'Drama, Mystery, Thriller',
  'IMDB_Rating': 7.6,
  'No_of_Votes': 256630,
  '_id': '60dae6af60d63d1fa2508e15',
  'text': '13 Reasons Why . HashtagTheBest! ',
  'hashtags': '[]',
  'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
  'score2': 0.0,
  'text_cleaned__punctuation': '13 Reasons Why  HashtagTheBest '},
 {'show_id': 's64',
  'type': 'TV Show',
  'title': '13 Reasons Why',
  'director': nan,
  'cast': "Dylan Minnette, Katherine Langford, Kate Walsh, Derek Luke, Brian d'Arcy James, Alisha Boe, Christian Navarro, Miles Heizer, Ross Butler, Devin Druid, Michele Selene Ang, Steven Silver, Amy Hargreaves",
  'country': 'United States',
  'rating': 'TV-MA',
  'duration': '4 Seasons',
  'Certificate': '16+',
  'Runtime_of_Episodes': '60 min',
  'Genre': 'Drama, Mystery, Thriller',
  'IMDB_Rating': 7.6,
  'No_of_Votes': 256630,
  '_id': '60dae6af60d63d1fa2509aca',
  'text': 'RT @haeriiisund: [ Haechan short Au ]\n\n—13 Reasons Why \n\n“Let me tell you 13 things about him that will make you fall for him.”\n\n©haeriisun…',
  'hashtags': '[]',
  'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
  'score2': 0.0,
  'text_cleaned__punctuation': 'RT   Haechan short u  —13 Reasons Why “Let me tell you 13 things about him that will make you fall for him” ©haeriisun…'}]

# For transformation, this is a list of keys to move under "tweets"
move = '_id','text','hashtags','score1','score2','text_cleaned__punctuation'

# Make sure data is sorted by the same key used by .groupby()
key = itemgetter('show_id')
data.sort(key=key)

result = []
for show_id,group in groupby(data,key=key):
    for i,item in enumerate(group):
        if i == 0: # first item is copied to result and an empty tweet list is created
            current = item  # keep a reference to the item to append later tweets in the group
            result.append(current)
            current['tweet'] = []

        current_tweet = {} # for each tweet, add it to the current_tweet list and move required keys into it
        current['tweet'].append(current_tweet)
        for movekey in move:
            current_tweet[movekey] = item[movekey]
            if i == 0: # delete moved keys from the first tweet in the group
                del current[movekey]

print(json.dumps(result,indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "show_id": "s64",
    "type": "TV Show",
    "title": "13 Reasons Why",
    "director": NaN,
    "cast": "Dylan Minnette, Katherine Langford, Kate Walsh, Derek Luke, Brian d'Arcy James, Alisha Boe, Christian Navarro, Miles Heizer, Ross Butler, Devin Druid, Michele Selene Ang, Steven Silver, Amy Hargreaves",
    "country": "United States",
    "rating": "TV-MA",
    "duration": "4 Seasons",
    "Certificate": "16+",
    "Runtime_of_Episodes": "60 min",
    "Genre": "Drama, Mystery, Thriller",
    "IMDB_Rating": 7.6,
    "No_of_Votes": 256630,
    "tweet": [
      {
        "_id": "60dae6af60d63d1fa2508e15",
        "text": "13 Reasons Why \ud83d\udc99. HashtagTheBest! \ud83d\ude2d",
        "hashtags": "[]",
        "score1": "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
        "score2": 0.0,
        "text_cleaned__punctuation": "13 Reasons Why  HashtagTheBest "
      },
      {
        "_id": "60dae6af60d63d1fa2509aca",
        "text": "RT @haeriiisund: [ Haechan short Au ]\n\n\u201413 Reasons Why \n\n\u201cLet me tell you 13 things about him that will make you fall for him.\u201d\n\n\u00a9haeriisun\u2026",
        "hashtags": "[]",
        "score1": "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
        "score2": 0.0,
        "text_cleaned__punctuation": "RT   Haechan short u  \u201413 Reasons Why \u201cLet me tell you 13 things about him that will make you fall for him\u201d \u00a9haeriisun\u2026"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```